# using more than one linestyle in the same trend line with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a line using the bold `linestyle='k-'` and after a certain value on the axes, I want the same line as dashed (`'k--'`) or vice-versa. I want to show the dashed part as an extension to the bold line. One way to do this is to treat them as two individual plots and use different `linestyles`. I have attached the figure of an example. Just wondering if there was any other way to do this!
[image]

Comment: I think you're right, you need to plot two lines. Of course, you can do this in one line, for example: `plot(x[:51],y[:51],'b--',x[50:],y[50:],'r-')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. Following the suggestion given by @tom, one such example is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,2,10)
y = np.linspace(1,2,10)

plt.plot(x[:4],y[:4],'-ko',x[3:],y[3:],'--ko')
plt.show()
```

This produces a plot:
[image]